# Tridion Audience Manager send Email send out

Tags: audience-manager

I'm encountering a bit of a strange issue with the audience manager profile sync.

We want to send an email from the front-end, using the audience manager api, to an existing user, by utilizing this:

```
contact = new Contact(contactident);
contact.save("tcm:75-132-64")
```

And i can see in the submgmt database that user gets the SEND_EMAIL_PAGE_URI set to the page specified above.

This does not get picked up by the synchronization in to tridion, until the user actually do a profile update, then it's get picked up and an email is sent.

I know this was something that was working previously in an earlier tridion version (2011GA) but have the behavior changed? (can't open the api for 2013SP1).
Do we have to change the last modified in some way in order to get this working?

Edit:
also want to point out that i have the following configured in outboundemail.xml

```
<ConfirmationEmailDefaults type="Subscribe">

<ConfirmationEmailDefaults type="OptedIn">

<ConfirmationEmailDefaults type="ChangeProfile">

<ConfirmationEmailDefaults type="Unsubscribe" >
```

and a bunch of :

```
<ConfirmationEmails>
<ConfirmationEmail page="tcm:75-132-64">
...
</confirmationEmail>
```

that have the same page id as i specify in the code.

Br Martin

Answer (score 3):

That functionality hasn't changed, no.

The most likely explanation is that you haven't configured "Subscribed" as an event that should result in an e-mail (but only "ChangeProfile" or perhaps "OptedIn"). Check the `ConfirmationEmailDefaults` and `ConfirmationEmails` sections of your *OutboundEmail.xml* configuration file.

Comment: Any other tips? See my edit

Comment: After reading your question again I get the sense that you are trying to send e-mails on the CD side that aren't related to the subscription system (and you aren't actually creating or modifying the Contact - just saving it). Is that right?

Comment: That's indeed the case here. As soon as the contact gets modified, the email is sent.

Comment: Well yes, because *that's* the intended behavior. You should not try to use it to send out other kinds of e-mails -- that's what Mailings are for :) So if you want them to receive subscription e-mails when they sign up (for explicit opt-in for instance), you should use this functionality and make sure you set the SubscriptionStatus property before saving. But if you just want to e-mail the Contacts, you should create Mailings on the Content Manager side and send those.

Comment: Let's say then, if we want to send an email based on user interaction (like entering email and hits send button) without beeing logged in. (and assuming the user exists)

Comment: I don't quite understand your scenario, but I could imagine you changing an Extended Detail field and then sending out Mailings to anyone with that value set. You can even make it triggered if you don't want it to be a manual action to send the e-mails (i.e. you just want them to receive the Mailing once, as soon as the Contacts have been synchronized). The bottom line is that you should try to use Mailings and not confirmation e-mails (which are very limited in scope and functionality)